# Can we use only one variable for many format descriptors in printf in C

Tags: c, variables, printf

Is is possible to write code like the one I've written in below ?

```
printf("\n%c%c\n%c",only_one_variable_for_all);
printf("%c%c%c\n",only_one_variable_for_all);
```

I have to print in different patterns in each case
Can you give any other ideas?

Comment: if you want to print multiple times, why don't you use a loop?

Comment: `printf(..., x, x, x);` Now it's used for all specifiers.

Comment: It's common to do things like `printf "%d %o %x\n", i, i, i)` to see a number's representation in different bases. But you have to repeat `i` multiple times in the call, as shown.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

Quoting `C11`, chapter  §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`* (applicale for `*printf()` family, all emphasis mine)

> The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream, under control
>   of the string pointed to by `format` that specifies how subsequent arguments are
>   converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the `format`, the behavior is
>   undefined. If the `format` is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
>   evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.** [...]

and, for a `format` string containing conversion specifiers,

> The `format` shall be a multibyte character sequence, beginning and ending in its initial
>   shift state. The `format` is composed of zero or more directives: ordinary multibyte
>   characters (not `%`), which are copied unchanged to the output stream; and **conversion
>   specifications, each of which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments,**
>   converting them, if applicable, according to the corresponding conversion specifier, and
>   then writing the result to the output stream.**

So, the bottom line, each conversion specification needs zero or more "corresponding" argument, and one argument, cannot correspond to multiple conversion specification in the `format` string. Each conversion specification needs their *own* argument.

---

Solution:

In case you want to print the same variable multiple times, like you're shown,

```
 printf("\n%c%c\n%c",only_one_variable_for_all);
```

you can simply use a loop!!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE; i++ ) 
 { 
      printf ("%c", only_one_variable ); 

      /* some more logic for line break?*/

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The C standard doesn't allow this, but on POSIX systems you can do something like this:

```
printf("%1$d %1$d %1$d\n", 17);
```

POSIX says:

> Conversions can be applied to the nth argument after the format in the argument list, rather than to the next unused argument. In this case, the conversion specifier character % (see below) is replaced by the sequence "%n$", where n is a decimal integer in the range [1,{NL_ARGMAX}], giving the position of the argument in the argument list.

It's a relatively unknown extension so be prepared for even very experienced C programmers to not know about it and yell at you if you use it. (it will fail code review). Also, it isn't even intended to be used for repeating one argument, but rather for translation format strings where certain languages might want to print things in different order. So I'd recommend against using it. Just write out the variable many times. Don't be lazy.

Comment: A *one*-based index?!?  In C?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's POSIX, they didn't make it up, they just documented someones craziness. I suspect that in whatever implementation that made this up first it was just an offset into the arguments (since this probably came before va_list because it's a real pain to implement with a va_list) and the format string itself was at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible. Each format specifier requires a respective argument.

However, you can solve this in many ways depending on the thing you want to print multiple times.
For example, you can create C-string that contains the chars and print it.

```
char str[] = {ch, ch, ch, 0};
printf("%s", str);
```

Or use a loop to print the value as many times as needed. But there's no generic way to solve this.